# Closure without parameters memoization works only with call()

Tags: groovy, memoization

I am trying to implement memoization for some of my closures in another class. But I am not able to make it work.

Memoization works properly when calling the closure using `.call()`. But it does not work when I call it normally like a method.

**Code:**

```
public class Tester  {

    static main (String[] args){

        Sample sample = new Sample();

        println sample.printer.call();  \\works
        println sample.printer.call();  \\works

        sample = new Sample();

        println sample.printer();  \\does not work
        println sample.printer();  \\does not work
    }
}

class Sample{

    def  printer= {
        println "inside"
        true;
    }.memoize();
}
```

**Console log:**

```
inside
true
true
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.Memoize$MemoizeFunction.doCall() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: call(), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), equals(java.lang.Object), isCase(java.lang.Object)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.Memoize$MemoizeFunction.doCall() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: call(), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), equals(java.lang.Object), isCase(java.lang.Object)
    at Tester.main(Tester.groovy:12)
```

Due to this , I will have to now change all my closure calls by using `call()`. Please let me know if the same can be achieved my normal method call.

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to be able to give a solution, the best I can do however is tell you what a quick look (and tries in groovyConsole) got me:

using the short syntax for closure calling directly on a local memoized closure works like a charm:

```
def memclosure = { println "foo" }.memoize()
memclosure()
memclosure()
```

so, it has something to do with the way, Groovy resolves

```
sample.printer()
```

in fact, as there is no method "printer" on this class, so "methodMissing" of the object metaClass (or "invokeMethod" in the default case) is triggered, which then looks if there is a property with the method name and then performs the "doCall" action on its value (**looks to a Groovy bug to me: in Groovy 2.4.4 it's in MetaClassImpl at line 1249**)

the problem here is, that not all closure implementation provide this doCall method: ComposedClosure, IteratorClosureAdapter and MethodClosure e.g. do provide a doCall, the objects from Memoize however do not.

perhaps someone has a better explanation and/or solution (apart from raising a bug ticket)

I got it working by attaching a "doCall" method to the metaClass of a memoized closure at runtime:

```
def dummy = { println "never called" }.memoize()
dummy.class.metaClass.doCall = { -> delegate.call() }
dummy.class.metaClass.doCall = { a -> delegate.call(a) }
dummy.class.metaClass.doCall = { a, b -> delegate.call(a, b) }
dummy.class.metaClass.doCall = { a, b, c -> delegate.call(a, b, c) }
// can you attach new methods to a metaClass with dynamic parameter count?
```

perhaps try to execute that somehow at start time and have a look if thats a feasible workaround

Comment: Thanks man. Will try the meta class method. A direct call would be much nicer but since this does not work, I have to resolve to using `call()` everywhere.

Comment: of course you could patch and compile your groovy version introducing a doCall into the memoize closure variant. and raising a groovy bug ticket would be a good idea.

Comment: the variant with the metaClass is only necessary on start of the program. after that you can call the memoized closures directly